# Chef / InSpec documentation

Tags: inspec

Good morning,

I have just installed inspec on an UBUNTU server
I tried to follow this tutorial : https://learn.chef.io/modules/try-inspec#/
But nothing worked as it was supposed to work
I tend to think that I didn't quite understand how this works

Can anyone with previous experience with InSpec help, please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you be more precise? What steps are you are taking, what kind of results (possibly with output) are you getting?

Comment: The thing is I didnt even knew how to make it work.. I was asking for some tutorials or any documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try this inspec official Tutorial which also has documetation: 
https://www.inspec.io/tutorials/